# Header overlap in iText5

Tags: java, pdf, layout, pdf-generation, itext

I created a header and footer for my PDF document using PdfPTables. I have specified the headers and footers in my PdfPageEventHelper's onStartPage and onEndPage event's respectively.

The issue I am facing is while adding a paragraph to my document.

When I create a new Paragraph as follows:

```
Paragraph content = new Paragraph("This is a test text");
try{
  pdfDocument.add(content);
} catch (DocumentException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The content overlaps with the header. What I need is to set the pargraph between the header and the footer. Can someone tell me what do I need to do in order to put the pargraph between the header and footer, instead of on them.

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Set Margin in bottom 20 more than required.
e.g. Generally you keep marging from bottom is 40.

```
document.setMargins(50, 45, 50, 40);
```

Now, Keep it 60.

```
writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
document.setMargins(50, 45, 50, 60);
document.setMarginMirroring(false);

writer.setPageEvent(new HeaderAndFooter());
document.open();
```

Now in HeaderFooter PageEvent set Footer at document.bottom() - 20 position.

```
public class HeaderAndFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    private Font footerFont;
    public HeaderAndFooter() {
        super();
        footerFont = getFontObj(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY, 15);
        footerFont.setStyle(Font.ITALIC);
    }


    @Override
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("Page %d", writer.getPageNumber()),footerFont), (document.left() + document.right())/2 , document.bottom()-20, 0);
    }
}
```

It will solve the problem of overlapping. It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the margins properly:

```
Document(Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom)
```

Comment: Thanks. But where do I set the margins? After the Header the Footers have been added? or Before? Also, do the margins get affected after the Headers and Footers have been added to the document? It seems like iText does not have the concept of relative positioning.

Comment: here you can set the margins, in the beginning: Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, *margins...*);