# IText html header/footer and table overlapping

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext

I developed a method that converts a HTML file into a .pdf file, but this HTML file contains a repeated footer and header in each page.

The problem is that the content contains a big table that when this table getting bigger it overrides the footer and the header of the next page..

Here is an example PDF.

[image: header footer overlapping]

Comment: How are you adding the table to the document. I've never seen this kind of behavior. Show us some code!

Comment: No link... Maybe something went wrong while copy/pasting. Also: which version of iText are you using?

Comment: I am using itext 2.0.8 not itextpdf, and here is a sample code:
https://gist.github.com/husseincoder/5433444

Comment: Still no code, but as iText 2.0.8 is no longer supported, there's no need to send it. See http://lowagie.com/itext2 for my opinion on people who are still importing my name into their code.

Comment: Please see this if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387728/header-overlap-in-itext/33167752#33167752