# iText5 PDF content getting overridden on Footer

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText5 with Java for creating pdf and creating document as

```
document = new Document(new Rectangle(1150f, 1150f));
```

My content of pdf is getting overridden on the footer( which is an image).

Footer code:

```
public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {    
        document.newPage();
        try {           
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(), Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("Page %d", writer.getPageNumber())), (document.left() + document.right())/2,document.bottom()-18,0);            
            Image image = Image.getInstance(PdfHeaderFooter.class.getResource("/static/images/SampleFooter.png"));
            image.scaleAbsolute(1100f, 75f);// image width,height
            image.setAbsolutePosition(30, 40);
            document.add(image);                           
        }
        catch(DocumentException de) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(de);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) { 
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));  
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));  
        }
    }
```

Also, some searches suggested [margin solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214007/itext-pdf-body-content-overlapping-on-footer-part). to set margin but I am not able to find the exact place to set the margin or any other solution.

Please help, how should I create a new page when content goes out of the pdf area and is not overlapped on footer image.

Comment: Please accept the answer by @mkl because he is right. Reading your code, it is obvious that you didn't read any of the documentation. Your code is completely wrong!

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issue in your code.

## `newPage()` during `onEndPage()`

The event callback `onEndPage()` is called during a page change; calling `document.newPage()` in that method, therefore, is probably hazardous, at least it is senseless.

## `document.add` during `onEndPage()`

As documented for iText and often mentioned in answers and comments on stackoverflow, *you shall not use `document.add` during `onEndPage()`.*

You can draw to the direct content (`PdfWriter.getDirectContent()`) or the background content (`PdfWriter.getDirectContentUnder()`).

## coordinates

You create the `Document` using:

```
document = new Document(new Rectangle(1150f, 1150f));
```

This constructor applies default margins of 36 units:

```
public Document(Rectangle pageSize) {
    this(pageSize, 36, 36, 36, 36);
}
```

Thus, your content will be written into the rectangle with 36 < x < 1114 and 36 < y < 1114.

Now you add your image like this

```
image.scaleAbsolute(1100f, 75f);// image width,height
image.setAbsolutePosition(30, 40);
```

The image position is the ***lower* left** corner of the image. Thus, you intend to draw the image in the rectangle with 30 < x < 1130 and 40 < y < 115.

Thus, the image obviously will overlap part of the content. Either move your image down or use explicit margins with a large enough bottom margin.

Comment: Thanks you so much.You are right, actually adding newPage at the end of the page is useless and it was added by mistake. I will adjust the coordinates as suggested by you.